# ListBox ItemTemplate - Display the property that the user selects at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which is bound to a `List` of `DataModel`.

DataModel.cs

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The `ListBox` should display two properties, so I have defined the `ItemTemplate` as below

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My requirement is that the user can select which two properties to display in the `ListBox` at run time. I am not sure how to achieve this. I have created a sample solution to explain my problem.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Label Content="Property One"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"></ComboBox>
            <Label Content="Property Two"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBox2" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"></ComboBox>
            <Button Content="Go" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="3"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelList}" Margin="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel();

        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<String> DataModelProperties { get; set; }

        public List<DataModel> DataModelList { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            DataModelList = new List<DataModel>();

            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name1", Code = "Code1", Desc = "Desc1" });
            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name2", Code = "Code2", Desc = "Desc2" });
            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name3", Code = "Code3", Desc = "Desc3" });

            DataModelProperties = typeof(DataModel).GetProperties().Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Things I have tried

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedItem}"></TextBlock>
```

This just displays the selected property name.

Answer (score 0):

In short, what I've done is I made 2 public properties to bind to and changed your properties to fields. Also I've made custom attribute, to control what fields user is able to select. And created a DisplayOptions class to store selection and spread it across DataModel instances.
The solution is a bit messy, considering it's a PoC, but I believe this can do:

XAML:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Label Content="Property One"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"></ComboBox>
            <Label Content="Property Two"></Label>
            <ComboBox Name="ComboBox2" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"></ComboBox>
            <Button Content="Go" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="3"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelList}" Margin="5">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayProperty1}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayProperty2}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

CS:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = model;
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This part has to be on the View side, but this is PoC
            model.Opts.Prop1 = typeof(DataModel).GetFields()
                .Where(a => a.Name == ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Opts.Prop2 = typeof(DataModel).GetFields()
                .Where(a => a.Name == ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            DataContext = null;
            DataContext = model;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public DisplayOptions Opts = new DisplayOptions();

        public List<String> DataModelProperties { get; set; }

        public List<DataModel> DataModelList { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            var properties = typeof(DataModel).GetFields()
              .Where(a => a.CustomAttributes.Any(b => b.AttributeType == typeof(SwitchableAttr)));

            //Initialising options before creating DataModel instances
            DataModelProperties = properties.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
            Opts.Prop1 = properties.ElementAt(0);
            Opts.Prop2 = properties.ElementAt(1);


            DataModelList = new List<DataModel>();
            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name1", Code = "Code1", Desc = "Desc1", options = Opts });
            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name2", Code = "Code2", Desc = "Desc2", options = Opts });
            DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name3", Code = "Code3", Desc = "Desc3", options = Opts });
        }
    }

    public class DisplayOptions
    {
        public FieldInfo Prop1;
        public FieldInfo Prop2;
    }

    public class DataModel
    {
        public DisplayOptions options;
        [SwitchableAttr]
        public string Name;
        [SwitchableAttr]
        public string Desc;
        [SwitchableAttr]
        public string Code;

        public string DisplayProperty1 { get { return (string)options.Prop1.GetValue(this); } set { } }
        public string DisplayProperty2 { get { return (string)options.Prop2.GetValue(this); } set { } }
    }

    public class SwitchableAttr : Attribute { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to manage all the stuff regarding the "dynamic description" showed in the ListBox in your ViewModel.

First of all, your view model and your model should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). In my sample I created a simple base class which implements it. My base class is called `NotifyPropertyChangedImpl`.

Moreover I added two properties to the view model: the comboboxes for selecting the properties are binded to those two properties.

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private string property1;
    private string property2;

    public List<String> DataModelProperties { get; set; }

    public List<DataModel> DataModelList { get; set; }

    public string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return property1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (property1 != value)
            {
                property1 = value;
                SetDynamicDescriptions();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Property2
    {
        get
        {
            return property2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (property2 != value)
            {
                property2 = value;
                SetDynamicDescriptions();
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        DataModelList = new List<DataModel>();

        DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name1", Code = "Code1", Desc = "Desc1" });
        DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name2", Code = "Code2", Desc = "Desc2" });
        DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = "Name3", Code = "Code3", Desc = "Desc3" });

        DataModelProperties = typeof(DataModel).GetProperties().Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
    }

    private void SetDynamicDescriptions()
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo1;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo2;

        Type type = typeof(DataModel);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(property1) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(property2))
        {
            propertyInfo1 = type.GetProperty(property1);
            propertyInfo2 = type.GetProperty(property2);

            foreach (DataModel dataModel in DataModelList)
            {
                dataModel.DynamicDescription = String.Format("{0} - {1}",
                    propertyInfo1.GetValue(dataModel, null), propertyInfo2.GetValue(dataModel, null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the method `SetDynamicDescriptions` rebuilds the DynamicsDescription each time Property1 or Property2 changes.

I also added a property to the model class:

```
public class DataModel : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private string dynamicDescription;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string DynamicDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return dynamicDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            if (dynamicDescription != value)
            {
                dynamicDescription = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicDescription");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So at the end your XAML will be:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
        <Label Content="Property One"></Label>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Property1}"></ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Property Two"></Label>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox2" Margin="3" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelProperties}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Property2}"></ComboBox>

    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelList}" Margin="5">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DynamicDescription}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Complete MVVM
so here is the code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;

    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox2.Text))
        {
            vm.AddDataToModel(ComboBox1.Text, ComboBox2.Text);
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<String> DataModelProperties { get; set; }


    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _DataModelList;


    public ViewModel()
    {
        _DataModelList = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

        DataModelProperties = typeof(DataModel).GetProperties().Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
    }
    public void AddDataToModel(string cmbx1Val,string cmbx2Val)
    {
        _DataModelList.Add(new DataModel() { Name = cmbx1Val, Code = cmbx2Val, Desc = "Desc1" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> DataModelList
    {

        get
        {
            return _DataModelList;
        }
        set
        {
            _DataModelList = value;

        }

    }



}
```